# What is the name of this HV test measuring setup?

Tags: high-voltage, measurement, test-equipment, high-power

There is a measuring setup similar to the following photo in our laboratory which belongs to PASSON VILLA company. What is the engineering name of this device and how can I find a catalog or something? Because as far as I know, this company has been dissolved.
[image]

Comment: A 19” rack with rack-mounted oscilloscope, panel meters and an e-stop?

Comment: This was likely built to order by a boutique system builder. These things are not usually off the shelf from a  major catalog company  , but will typically  use off the shelf equipment integrated to meet the users need.

Comment: @crasic THANKS, overall, what do we call such this setup? (as this is my second language)

Comment: Nomenclature is highly regional, to me this is a test system or test equipment. It can also be refered to as a test station, a test setup, a test rig, or sometimes a test fixture. You mention it test HV, specific types of tests can be referred to as such, e.g. ESD discharge test system. I find it best to focus on the *capabilities* that you desire from your system.

Comment: It does appear that Passon**i** Villa was at least moderately succesfull system builder.Appears that this company: http://www.hvts.net/ purchased their IP (See: http://www.hvts.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=61&Itemid=281&lang=en) and is offering support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bespoke test rig for testing transformers or similar large power equipment to some applicable standard(s). Knowing the standards you need to test to (eg. CEI 14-4/8) should lead a list of the required test equipment or at least a better idea of what is required.

The racks contain some standard test equipment and probably some customized bits in rack panels to glue them together, plus an old desktop computer with CRT monitor that appears to have been superseded by the notebook computer.

You can even find customized software for this purpose (eg. TestTeam in Italy).

Answer (score 3):

That looks like [impulse test equipment](https://hvtechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/HVT-Impulse-Test-Equipment-Brochure-Rev.-10_2021.pdf). (There are a few hints: the impulse waveshape on the screen, the faraday caged windows, and the voltage divider (donut-shaped) in the back.)

This equipment is used for testing equipment according to (for example) IEC requirements for lightning impulse withstand voltage, and switching impulse withstand voltage.

When I was in the high voltage testing bay of a major Australian electrical manufacturer, I noted that all the high voltage test gear was manufactured by  Haefely Hipotronics, since acquired by [Hubbell](https://www.hubbell.com/hipotronics/en).

I believe Hipotronics will [supply the complete system](https://hvtechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/HVT-Impulse-Test-Equipment-Brochure-Rev.-10_2021.pdf), including the impulse generator, control system, measuring instruments, and software.